# How to apply delta changes of JSON into original object in Jackson / Play 2.0?

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

The backend receives modification to existing object as a PUT request. The body contains only the changed fields.

What would be the best way to apply changes in to the original Java object?

Edit:
Objects updates are shallow, no deep copy. Original object...

```
'car' : {'id':'34','brand':'Ford','type':'Pinto','color':'blue','owner':'joe'}
```

Update as PUT /car/34 with body...

```
'car' : {'color':'red','owner':null}
```

Should result...

```
'car' : {'id':'34','brand':'Ford','type':'Pinto','color':'red','owner':null}
```

Comment: Without examples, it is difficult to tell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From security point of view:

- Fetch required object from DB
- Iterate through nodes of incoming Json
- Validate data for each node (types+allowed values/ranges)
- Update selected fields of object
- Update object in the DB

Comment: Side note: The HTTP method should be a `POST` in this case.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WXYw4J4QOU

Using `PUT` for an update should send the entire object, not a delta.